# Hooking into Terminal Services Manager

Tags: vb.net, terminal-services

Has anyone ever come across a way of a way to create an app that kind of mimics what Terminal Services manager does in Windows2003/XP.

I would like to write something that would either go and query a farm of server every n secs a get me a list of users logged in, there process's etc or do maybe type a username in and it goes and finds the user in the farm and returns their details.

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [Cassia](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/), a .NET library which uses internally the Wtsapi32 library Arnshea mentioned. For example, to list all users logged into a server:

```
Dim manager As New TerminalServicesManager()
Using server As ITerminalServer = manager.GetRemoteServer("your-server-name")
    server.Open()
    For Each session As ITerminalServicesSession In server.GetSessions()
        If Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(session.UserName) Then Console.WriteLine(session.UserName)
    Next
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

I've hacked this using qwinsta (query winstation is the mnemonic) and string parsing/regular expressions.  Beware of firewalls and impersonation.

Comment: i saw this but it looked a bit clumsy, is the no API available?

Comment: There is (wtsapi32.dll) but there's a bit of a learning curve and it's use will vary depending on the environment in which it's run.  It's a COM/ActiveX api but you're out of luck when it comes to tlbs...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and the other ps* utilities from Microsoft (originally from SysInternals).